# error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: javascript, typescript

/node_modules/lib/index.js

```
class AbstractPartnerInstance {
    #partner = null;

    constructor(partner) {
        this.#partner = partner;
    }

    get data() {
        return this.#partner;
    }

    static async schema(partner) {
        throw new Error();
    }

    static get version() {
        throw new Error();
    }
}


module.exports = { AbstractPartnerInstance };
```

extends
test.ts

```
import { AbstractPartnerInstance } from 'lib';

class PartnerInstance extends AbstractPartnerInstance  {

    static get version(): any {
        return 2;
    }
}

error >> const test = new PartnerInstance('af');
```

i am extending class(ts) from class(js). for some reason this causes an error:
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)

I can not understand why the extended class does not see the constructor?